# How to update entities automatically when the underlying database tables/stored procedures have been changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity

Is it possible to update the edmx model automatically or make the entity model notify (throw error) if the underlying tables or stored procedures have been changed by db admin.I have created entities for an existing database. Im using entity framework 4.0 with mvc 3.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the change there would indeed be a runtime error.  This sounds like less of a code issue and more of a process issue, though.  It sounds like the database admin is skipping things like change control, source control, etc.

Comment: im not getting a runtime error. example if im using a stored procedure thro EF and my stord proc has been changed(no of parameters for stored proc from  two to three) by dbadmin. it doesnt throw any error. instead it returns null values from stored proc.

Comment: The *root* of the problem is that code is being changed without updating the code which relies on it. You could perhaps litter the code with sanity checks for things like this (since it doesn't sound like it's doing it automatically), but that doesn't address the cause of the problem, only a symptom. The problem is that someone is modifying code in the system and making breaking changes without any accountability. When the stored procedure is changed, it should be updated in source control. Tests should be run against the updated code before deploying it. It sounds like that's not happening.